# main module not running in CLI

Tags: python

I have a project structure like this

```
project
|--invoices
  |--abc_company
  |--xyc_company
|--scripts
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- extract_xyz_data.py
 |-- extract_abc_data.py
 |-- extract_data.py
 |-- utilities.py
 |-- abc_validation.py
 |-- xyz_validation.py
|--main.py
```

my main.py scripts calls the extract_data.py script from scripts folder. Within extract_data.py, I am calling other scripts like extract_abc_data.py and it finally prints out the extraction using print statements and returns a extracted_dir.

Here is how main.py looks

```
# main module
import argparse

from scripts.extract_data import extract_data

def main():
    """ Main Module to run the script

    """

    # Creating a parset object
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Adding Invoice Directory path
    parser.add_argument('invoice_dir_path',
                       action='store',
                       type =str,
                       default = './invoices',
                       help='Pass the directory path of invoice folder (ex ./invoices)')

    # Adding Template directory path
    parser.add_argument('templates_dir_path',
                       action='store',
                       default = './templates',
                       type =str,
                       help='Pass the directory path of templates folder')

    # Adding USD Rate param

    parser.add_argument('usd_rate',
                       action='store',
                       default = 0.72,
                       type =float,
                       help='Enter the USD Rate')


    # Adding Month of Invoice Billing

    parser.add_argument('month',
                       action='store',
                       type =str,
                       help='Enter month of billing in words (ex. Dec/December')

     

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(vars(args))


    print("calling extract_data")
    extracted_dir = extract_data(args)

    print(extracted_dir)



    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I run it on terminal by being in project directory and run

```
python main.py ./invoices ./templates 0.72 dec
```

And I get nothing. There is no error, not output, not extracted_dir created. Even the print statements I put above in def main(), don't get printed to console.

Pls help.

Comment: Because your import guard is indented into the function body

Comment: Voting to close as typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the entry point inside the main function

```py
def main():
   # ... code
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
```

You need it outside of that initial block:

```py
def main():
    # ... code
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: My god!! such a typo and I spent 45 mins figuring why its not working :(

Comment: Hahaha, no worries I don't know anyone who hasn't been burned by a silly mistake like that!

Comment: hi quick q. I have defined few packages in main.py right at the top like 

import os 
import pandas as pd

Now in other scripts likes extract_data etc, I am using os and pandas. 

Do I still need to import these packages in those scripts again or it can take it from the main.py import? Because when I do just in main.py, it gives error for these packages not found in other scripts when they are run. All those scripts I am importing in main.py

Comment: No you'll need to re-import those packages. Look here for more in depth explanation: https://realpython.com/python-import/.